# R Machine Learning Model - Blind Test

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am working in a model for a competition, we were provided with 2 datasets:

**Dataset A**: Does contain the label, to be used to train/test the model.
***Dataset B***: Does not contain the label, this data is to be used in a blind test, and based in the predictions a score is assigned.

I am ready with the model, however when using the function `predict()` with the ***Dataset B*** (for the blind test) one question came up, Do I have to apply the same pre-processing steps (remove duplicates, NAs, Scale Numeric Features) applied in the **Dataset A?** And what about the NAs? Looking in the Dataset B several NAs were included.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, I think you should apply the same pre-processing steps.  As for those `NA` values, if a given column have only a handful of `NA`, one quick fix would be to just replace them with the columns mean or median.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have to apply the same pre-processing applied to data set A, duplicates, remove NA, Scale Numeric Features. For predictions could be affected. Dame puntos amigo.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the predict function you will need to clean your data.You can use the `completecases()` function if you want to get rid of all your NAs. You shouldn't remove duplicates unless you have a record number or a unique key.

```
datasetb.2<-datasetb[completecases(datasetb), ]
predicted<-predict(datasetA.model, newdata = datasetb.2)
accuracy<-(actual==predicted)/nrow(datasetb.2)
```